# Simple question about using names in else-if statements:

Tags: java

I'm new and I need some guidance on how to use names in Java. I tried to use names to trigger the else if statements but I don't know how they work.

```java
public class Else_If_Statements {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int flavor = Chocolate;
        
        
        if (flavor = Vanilla)
            system.out.println("That will be 3$!");
        else if (flavor = Caramel)
            system.out.println("That will be 6$!");
        else if (flavor = Chocolate)
            system.out.println("That will be 5$!");
        else 
            system.out.println("Sorry, that flavor isn't available!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: in Java, is `flavor = Vanilla` assignment or test for equality - you know, like in javascript and C and many other langauges

Comment: What is `Vanilla`, `Caramel`, and `Chocolate`? Are they globals or do you mean that to be *strings*? If they are to be strings, you have to declare `flavor` to be of type `String` not `int`. Also, if they are strings, then you need to surround them in quotes: `"Vanilla"`, `"Caramel"`, and `"Chocolate"`. Next, `flavor = Vanilla` performs *an assignment*, you want `flavor == Vanilla` to do a comparison (or `flavor = "Vanilla"` if it's supposed to be a string). Finally, please don't use code snippets if your code doesn't work in them. They are for showcasing code that can run.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Or Car is to Carpet

Comment: Also take a look at Java's naming conventions. You don't use "_" in class names but rather capitalize the first letters like this *ElseIfStatements*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, the if else works this way. The named value to be assigned to the String datatype and equals() method has to be used for the comparison.

```
public class Else_If_Statements {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String flavor = "Chocolate";
        
        
        if (flavor.equals("Vanilla"))
            System.out.println("That will be 3$!");
        else if (flavor.equals("Caramel"))
            System.out.println("That will be 6$!");
        else if (flavor.equals("Chocolate"))
            System.out.println("That will be 5$!");
        else 
            System.out.println("Sorry, that flavor isn't available!");
    }
}
```